# SCSS в браузере не корректно отображает файл

Tags: scss

Только перешел на SCSS и сделал на нём первый макет и когда делал его в Live server то все было гуд. Но когда я закончил макет и решил просто открыть индексный файл то кроме как простого текста без стилей не увидел... файл стилей вообще не подтянулся в браузер, с чем это может быть связано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ммм попытаюсь объяснить как я это вижу (я новичок сори :) ). Имеется файл Index.html, style.css, style.scss. Так вот до того как перейти на scss верстал всё в простом css и для просмотра результата моей работы по завершению макета я сохраняю файл закрываю всё. Открываю файл index.html и смотрю всё ли хорошо сделал. В этой же ситуации я верстал макет в SCSS первый раз... и после открытия как обычно индексного файла для проверки своей вёрстки я немного не понял куда подевались все стили)) так как в Live server (VS code) всё работает хорошо, то есть отображается в браузере правильно, а здесь нет

Вот так выглядит всё в Live Server Vs code:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так. А где кофе?

Comment: А можно код и нормальные скриншоты? Потому как, например, я -- не экстрасенс.